# Unsupported Media Type error when uploading file

Tags: c#, .net-core, postman

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file, CarModel model = null)
{    
}
```

from the postman but I'm getting Error 415
[image]

I'm sending header `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` tried with `Content-Type: application/json` but it doesn't work either.

**Update:**
*Just realize that this error gone if I remove second parameter from the Upload method*

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
{    
}
```

I'm confused now. Why is this happening? and how should I implement Upload method to receive 2nd parameter?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it at the first glance. Is the route `/file/upload` correct? Can you add raw request and response from Postman console into your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the file variable to my input model to make it work right.

```cs
public class UploadModel
{
    //Other inputs

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public List<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }
}

public class SomeController
{

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(UploadModel model)
    {    
        var file = model.Files.First();
    }
}
```